# How to find a unique button that has no name or id?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a webpage that has multiple containers that each have a header (fooHeading), name (fooName), and a button (fooButton).

There would be multiple containers on the same page that look as follows:

```
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
fooTitle fooButton
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
```

The html for each container looks identical to the following:

```
<div class="fooHeading">
    <span class="fooName">

        fooTitle

    </span>
    <button class="fooButton"></button>
</div>
```

FooTitle is the only thing that would change. How can I uniquely click fooButton based on what fooTitle is?

Comment: Documentation helps: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_locating_techniques.jsp

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend xpath:

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'fooTitle')]/../button"));
```

This will find a `span` that contains the text `fooTitle`.  The `..` will go up to the `div`, then find the `button` that is the child of the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered such problem in the my project while creating scripts in selenium sometime all traditional method fails like **xpath,css selector** ,etc.

if same happens with you then my approach may help you 
first you have to check total count of button tag from starting then find the position of count of your button e.g. its position is **pos**

```
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.tagName("button"));
Iterator<WebElement> itr = element.iterator();
int count=0;
WebElement e = null ;

while(itr.hasNext())
{
    count++;

    e = (WebElement) itr.next();

    if(count==pos)
        break;
}

//System.out.println(count);
//for checking total count without using break in while loop

e.click();
```